# Highlight matched character foreground color?

Tags: vim, colors, nvim

I have setup Vim to highlight trailing whitespace:

```
set listchars=eol:↵,nbsp:◦,tab:―→,trail:⮿,extends:⮚,precedes:⮘
set list " Show problematic characters.

" Also highlight all tabs and trailing whitespace characters.
highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=red guibg=red
match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
```

This works fine and sets a red highlighted background on trailing whitespace characters.

Is there a way to instead set the foreground color of the text rather than the background? I can't seem to get it to trigger using ctermfg and guifg.

Comment: You want to change the foreground color of whitespace?

Comment: Yes, I want to change the font color.